# Clear all page style for a specific div and it's child elements

Tags: javascript, css

I have some html being embeded on websites but is gets messed by the page it's embeded in's css. How can I make it so that doesnt happen... My content has a specific ID and it's css is very specific. It contains images, divs, spans, h tags, p tags.. all the usual stuff. The style sheet for MY div is appended to the head.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `!important` to the CSS properties that are being affected. Ex. `font-size:14px!important`. That is, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I added that to my style but it made no difference as there are things I dont have defined such as image margin. WOuld I need to add every definition to clear all page css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided I understood your question correctly, you could [recursively](http://javascript.about.com/library/blrecursive.htm) iterate through the [child elements](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_nodetree.asp) of your `div` with JavaScript and reset the [`class`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_class.asp) and [`style`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_style.asp) attributes. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PcbHw/) or the following code snippet:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .aClass {
                font-size: 0.75em;
            }

            .anotherClass {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: Fuchsia;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function removeStuff(elem) {
                elem.children().each(function() {
                    if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
                        $(this).removeClass();
                        $(this).removeAttr('style');
                        removeStuff($(this));
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass();
                        $(this).removeAttr('style');
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <span class="aClass">This span is classy.</span>
            <div style="font-size: 2em;">
                This div has style.
                <span class="anotherClass">Lorem Ipsum.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:removeStuff($('#myDiv'));">Remove classes &amp; styles</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My div and its contents are being writting by jQuery so this could be the way to go... cold you please give me an example?

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much. Pefect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Target you specific content always through the ID and add specific classes. In addition, add !important to every rule in your CSS. And override all things you need to stay the same.

Other solution would be to use inline CSS for your content.