# How to not apply a webpage's CSS on the div I am inserting into it via content scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension in which I insert a div into webpage's body and set it's CSS position to fixed so that it floats over the page.

However, the host page's CSS gets applied over the div I am inserting and I don't want that to happen. How can I avoid that?

I tried applying normalize.css to get rid of the css being applied by host page but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7846052/588079  Also, have you tried inline styles (or using the style attribute using javascript)?

Comment: I haven't tried inline styles. Will have a look. Although, I will have to insert those into that head of host page, right? Not sure how to do that. Will try the above answer, too.

Comment: The above code does work but it removes all the styling, including the styles I was applying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are three solutions, the first one being ideal:

Put your content into an iframe. The parent's css won't apply inside of it. [**Demo here (click).**](http://jsbin.com/OXAMArU/1/edit)

Reset every css style on your element and all of its children. [**See this answer (click).**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903168/1435655)

Use inline styles all the way.

Comment: I need to interact with the host page. So, I think the iFrame option won't work.

Comment: @Jatin I found that link and I made a demo of the iframe solution. See my update.

Comment: I tried the iframe method in my extension. Can't seem to get it to work. I basically need an angular.js app inside that iframe but angular's not working, seems like iframe can't access the scripts I want it to access.

Comment: @Jatin that also can be done, but it's off topic for this post. I'd be glad to help if you make a question with all of the details about the iframe and scripts. Post the link to the question and I'll give it a go.

Comment: I got it working in the iframe! Thanks for your help! Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to write a small function that tries to create an unique ID (or classname) (essentially, check if the ID exists, if so, increment an appended number), then add an inline style-script that normalizes that specific div and all of it's children and finally add your div with this unique ID (or classname).

Example:

```
function addDiv(){
  var uId = (function(){
              for(var r='myUniqueId', i=1; document.getElementById(r+i); i++);
              return r+i;
            })()
  ,   div = document.createElement('div')
  ;

  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
          .appendChild(document.createElement('style'))
          .innerHTML = '#'+uId+ '{background-color:red;}'     //just as example
                     + '#'+uId+ ' .test{background-color:yellow;}';  
  div.id=uId;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
          .appendChild(div)
          .innerHTML='<p class="test">foo</p> <br> bar';  //just as example
}
```

[Working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gJjt2/)